# Is the average of primes up to $n$ smaller than $\frac{n}{2}$, if $n > 19$?

Tags: prime-numbers, integers

For $n = 19$, the average $\frac{(2 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 11 + 13 + 17 + 19)}{ 8} = \frac{77}{8}$ is greater than $\frac{19}{2}$ but for $n > 19$, it seems that the average is smaller than $n/2$.

I confirmed it holds for all $n < 10^7$ but have not been able to prove it for all n. How can I prove this?

Comment: You can probably prove this with a good bound related to the Prime Number Theorem.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE. FYI, a similar question is [What are the lower and upper bounds for the sum of the first $n$ primes?](/q/3676914), plus the answers at both [Sum of the first n Prime numbers](/a/439305) & [An asymptotic formula for the bounded sum of primes.](/a/1313158) state $\sum_{p\le n}p=\frac12\frac{n^2}{\log(n)}+O\left(\frac{n^2}{\log(n)^2}\right)$. Since the PNT states the # of primes up to $n$ to asymptotically is $\frac{n}{\log n}$, dividing by this gives the average to be $\frac{n}{2} + O\left(\frac{n}{\log(n)}\right)$. Thus, your bound is difficult, maybe not possible, to prove.

Comment: FYI, your question is similar to Mandl's inequality which asserts that $\frac{n}{2}p_n - \sum_{i=1}^{n}p_n \gt 0$ for $n \ge 9$. The lower bound is increased to $0.01659n^
2$ in [A Refinement of Mandl's Inequality](https://vuir.vu.edu.au/18085/1/refmandl.pdf). Note this result can be used to prove your conjecture is true, at least for all sufficiently large $n$.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is yes for sufficiently large $n$. Sketch of proof:

- Using [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) (as in [either one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313099/an-asymptotic-formula-for-the-bounded-sum-of-primes/1313158#1313158) of [these two existing answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439289/sum-of-the-first-n-prime-numbers/439305#439305)), the average in question is
  $$
  \frac1{\pi(n)}\sum_{p\le n} p = \frac1{\pi(n)} \biggl( n\pi(n) - \sum_{k<n} \pi(k) \biggr) = n - \frac1{\pi(n)} \sum_{k<n} \pi(k).
  $$
- Instead of just using $\pi(x) = \dfrac x{\log x} + O\biggl( \dfrac x{\log^2 x} \biggr)$, we use the more precise
  $$
  \pi(x) = \dfrac x{\log x} + \dfrac x{\log^2 x} +O\biggl( \dfrac x{\log^3 x} \biggr)
  $$
  that follows from the [asymptotic expansion of the logarithmic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function#Asymptotic_expansion).
- If we write
  $\displaystyle
  \pi(n) = \dfrac n{\log n} \biggl( 1 + \dfrac 1{\log n} + O\biggl( \dfrac1{\log^2 n} \biggr) \biggr)
  $
  and use $(1+\varepsilon)^{-1} = 1-\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)$, we see that
  $$
  \frac1{\pi(n)} = \dfrac{\log n}n \biggl( 1 - \dfrac 1{\log n} + O\biggl( \dfrac1{\log^2 n} \biggr) \biggr).
  $$
- Since the function $\dfrac x{\log^\alpha x}$ is increasing for $x>e^\alpha$, it's easy to see that $\displaystyle \sum_{k<n} \frac k{\log^\alpha k} = \int_2^n \frac t{\log^\alpha t}\,dt + O(n)$.
- Integration by parts yields $\displaystyle \int_2^n \frac t{\log^\alpha t}\,dt = \frac{n^2}{2\log^\alpha n} + O(1) + \frac{\alpha}2 \int_2^n \frac t{\log^{\alpha+1} t}\,dt$. It follows that
  $\displaystyle
  \int_2^n \frac t{\log^2 t}\,dt = \frac{n^2}{2\log^2 n} + O\biggl( \frac{n^2}{\log^3 n} \biggr)
  $ and
  $\displaystyle\int_2^n \frac t{\log t}\,dt = \frac{n^2}{2\log n} + \frac{n^2}{4\log^2 n} + O\biggl( \frac{n^2}{\log^3 n} \biggr)
  $.

Putting these all together:
\begin{align*}
\frac1{\pi(n)} \sum_{p\le n} p &= n - \frac1{\pi(n)} \sum_{k<n} \biggl( \dfrac k{\log k} + \dfrac k{\log^2 k} + O\biggl( \dfrac k{\log^3 k} \biggr) \biggr) \\
&= n - \frac1{\pi(n)} \biggl( \int_2^n \frac t{\log t}\,dt + \int_2^n \frac t{\log^2 t}\,dt + O\biggl( \int_2^n \frac t{\log^3 t}\,dt + n\biggr) \biggr) \\
&= n - \dfrac{\log n}n \biggl( 1 - \dfrac 1{\log n} + O\biggl( \dfrac1{\log^2 n} \biggr) \biggr) \\
&\qquad{}\times\biggl( \biggl( \frac{n^2}{2\log n} + \frac{n^2}{4\log^2 n} \biggr) + \frac{n^2}{2\log^2 n} + O\biggl( \frac{n^2}{\log^3 n} \biggr) \biggr) \\
&= n - \biggl( \frac n2 + \frac n{4\log n} + O\biggl( \frac n{\log^2n} \biggr) \biggr) = \frac n2 - \frac n{4\log n} + O\biggl( \frac n{\log^2n} \biggr),
\end{align*}
which finishes the proof.

Comment: FYI, see [A Refinement of Mandl's Inequality](https://vuir.vu.edu.au/18085/1/refmandl.pdf).

Comment: hey uh... when I tried this problem previously, someone told me you can't use asymptotic estimates as equations... why not? I'm not really good at math (high school student) but it seems like you're doing just that...? can you tell me why it's okay in this particular instance?

Comment: There are algebraic rules for manipulating $O$-terms, similar to those we learned for manipulating true equalities. With experience one learns which algebraic manipulations are valid and which are pitfalls.

Comment: can you give me a link on where i can learn this? it seems really cool!! c:

Comment: I learned these techniques in general from Montgomery and Vaughan's book *Multiplicative Number Theory I*.

Answer (score 3):

Mandl's inequality (see for example [this paper of Axler](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL18/Axler/axler6.pdf)) states that
$$
\frac{1}{m}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^m {p_k }  < \frac{{p_m }}{2}
$$
for $m\geq 9$. If $n\geq 23$, then $\pi(n)\geq 9$. Thus,
$$
\frac{1}{{\pi (n)}}\sum\limits_{p \le n} p  = \frac{1}{{\pi (n)}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{\pi (n)} {p_k }  < \frac{{p_{\pi (n)} }}{2} \le \frac{n}{2}.
$$
For $n=20,21$ and $22$, the inequality can be checked by hand.