# When finding $N$ primes will the total sum of $N$ primes always be $< 2^N$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

The prime gaps grow logarithmically.  Now, suppose I create a list of $N$ primes. 
For example $N = 10$ or $[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]$ then

$$\text{total~sum} = 129$$
$$2^N = 1024$$

### Question

Will the $total~sum$ of the list always be less than $2^N$?

Comment: Give me examples in the answer.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439289/sum-of-the-first-n-prime-numbers

Comment: @gt6989b Wow!!!

Comment: The inequality only kicks in at $N=5$. E.g., $2+3+5+7=17\gt2^4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very elementary way to prove it is to observer that starting with $p_4=7$
$$p_n<2^{n-1} \tag{1}$$
which can be shown by induction and using [Bertrand's postulate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_postulate)
$$p_{n+1}< 2p_n<2^{n}$$
Then $\forall N\geq 6$ we have 
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^N p_k
=\sum\limits_{k=1}^5 p_k + \sum\limits_{k=6}^N p_k
=28+\sum\limits_{k=6}^N p_k<
28+\sum\limits_{k=6}^N 2^{k-1}<\\
31+\sum\limits_{k=6}^N 2^{k-1}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^N 2^{k-1}=\frac{2^N-1}{2-1}=2^N-1<2^N$$
Of course, $N=5$ can be tested manually.