# For every $n \in \mathbb {N} $, assume $p_{n}$ is the $n^{th}$ prime number. if $n \gt 1$, prove that $p_{n}\lt 2^{n}$.

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, provability

I tried to solve this problem using mathematical induction. First, we say that $ 3 \lt 4$ for $n =2$, which is correct.
Then by assuming that it's accurate for $k$, we need to prove it's accurate as well for each $ k+1$.
$$p_{k+1} \lt 2^{k+1} \Rightarrow p_{k+1} \lt 2^{k} \times 2 \Rightarrow \cfrac{p_{k+1}}{2} \lt 2^{k} $$
I don't know how should I prove it at last and I don't know if this is the way of solving this or not. Can someone correct me if I'm wrong and help me figure out the rest?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand's_postulate

Comment: This is not exactly what I would call a problem for beginners.

Comment: There is an even lower bound (that has been proven): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206815/is-there-a-way-to-show-that-sqrtp-n-n

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Unless say the context is a class where they've covered whatshisname's $n<p<2n$  thing, and the exercise is just to recognize the relevance...

Comment: It's even [more surprising](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3690295/when-finding-n-primes-will-the-total-sum-of-n-primes-always-be-2n/3690709#3690709). Use it as an example ...